# tasm 1.4 color code orange instead of yellow

Tags: colors, tasm

```
    mov ah,06h 
    mov bh,60h; - its for the color yellow it shows orange
    mov ch,7
    mov cl,6
    mov dh,7
    mov dl,6
    int 10h
```

this is the pic 
https://www.zeta-uploader.com/en/openfile?hash=1248851038&rel=1248851038.png&r=https%3a%2f%2fwww.zeta-uploader.com%2fen&s=397015302

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the high intensity bit of the color turned on. The value you need is 0xe0.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_color_attributes

Comment: Since you want to change the background color, it could be necesary to first disable the *blinking* feature in order to enable the high intensity color.